# Android Realm Handling Primary Key in Relational Object

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, realm, realm-list

I have two objects: `MailBox` and `Email`.  Each Receiver has many `Emails`.

```
public class MailBoxRealmModel extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;

    private String name;
    private String mailboxId;
    private RealmList<EmailRealmModel> emails;
}

public class EmailRealmModel extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private long EmailId;

    private String Name;
    private String Text;
    private String Tag;
    private int Type;
    private String Time;
    private int Status;
}
```

How can one use `**realm.insertOrUpdate**`when adding email to MailBoxRealmModel?

```
EmailRealmModel email = new EmailRealmModel();
email.setMessageId(emailID);

realm.insertOrUpdate(email );

mailBoxRealmModel.getEmails().add(email);
```

I am getting a null pointer exception `email` on this line:

`mailBoxRealmModel.getEmails().add(email);`

Exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean io.realm.RealmList.add(io.realm.RealmModel)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                        at com.koa.mailbox.MailBoxActivity$1.execute(MailBoxActivity.java:123)
>                                                                                        at io.realm.Realm.executeTransaction(Realm.java:1253)
>                                                                                        at com.koa.mailbox.MailBoxActivity.test(MailBoxActivity.java:88)
>                                                                                        at com.koa.mailbox.MailBoxActivity.onCreate(MailBoxActivity.java:71)
>                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
>                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3207)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) 
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

Comment: Can you show the full exception message?

Comment: I did add my ex

Comment: The problem is your `mailBoxRealmModel` is an unmanaged RealmObject. How did you get the `mailBoxRealmModel`?

Answer (score 1):

Proper way to create a new RealmObject with existing primary key is usage  `realm.createObject(EmailRealmModel.class, emailID)`method.

Full code fragment:

```
realm.beginTransaction();
EmailRealmModel email = realm.createObject(EmailRealmModel.class, emailID);
mailBoxRealmModel.getEmails().add(email);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Or, if you wish update stored in realm object using one of inmemory instances, you should call `realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(obj)`.

Example from [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#primary-keys):

```
// For create managed proxy, you should wrap EmailRealmModel object by call copyToRealmXXX
EmailRealmModel email = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(new EmailRealmModel(id));
mailBoxRealmModel.getEmails().add(email);
```

Comment: I know that, but I have multiple Emails that might have the same Id, so i need to update my records, so i want to use **realm.insertOrUpdate**

Comment: alright but when i create **MyObject obj = new MyObject();** 
the **obj** give me null pointer on this line mailBoxRealmModel.getEmails().add(email);

Comment: Java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean io.realm.RealmList.add(io.realm.RealmModel)' on a null object reference

Comment: According this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30357069/3926506) "- It is because you are trying to add a non-managed object to a managed list". I'm fixing example for your's task

Comment: Inner transaction not required. Just work with your wrapped objects

Answer (score 0):

On an unmanaged RealmObject, the `RealmList` fields must be initialized manually.

```
EmailRealmModel email = new EmailRealmModel();
email.setMessageId(emailID);

mailBoxRealmModel.setEmails(new RealmList<MailBoxRealmModel>());
mailBoxRealmModel.getEmails().add(email);
realm.insertOrUpdate(mailBoxRealmModel);
```